# By-product and Nth-product

Tags: numbers

By-products is a secondary product derived from a production process of primary product.

Is there anything like tri-product, four, five .. Nth?

Thank you.

Comment: A process can have many by-products.

Comment: @Xanne You mean every secondary, tertiary and nth product of any process is known as by-product?

Answer (score 2):

The term *By* is originally an adverbial particle of place, meaning proximity, nearness. [etymonline.com]

So being a byproduct refers more to it being a minor result or side effect of the process rather than the major, primary result.

Spelled differently the term *Bi* indicates two or twice of a thing. Bi and tri- can enumerate things reaching the Nth item in general. These are not used to precede *Product* to describe the various elements of a process.

Comment: And this one too